# Calculate the sequence : n!/ (1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n)

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization

Calculate the following sum
1!/1 + 2!/(1+1/2) + 3!/(1+1/2+1/3) + ... + n!/ (1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n), where n > 0.

```
public static double GetSumSix(int n)
    {
        double i, result = 0.0;

        static double factorial(double n)
        {
            double res = 1;
            for (double i = 2; i <= n; i++)
                res *= i;

            return res;
        }

        for (i = 1.0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            result += factorial(i) / (1.0 / i);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Help me please , I don't understand why is my solution not working?

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Your `result += factorial( i ) / ( 1.0 / i )` does not include the summed fractions in the denominator below the factorial (e.g. `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ...`). You'll need to figure that part out.

Comment: Unit tests give an error, I don't know why, this is a task from the course

Comment: Have you stepped through this with the debugger.. When you did, which iteration of the loops were giving the wrong result?

Comment: What error do the tests give? You haven't given us any information that would be beneficial to diagnosing this. Please remember that only you know what you are doing and what issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your denominator logic is incorrect. You could create another function to work out what '1/1+1/2+...+1/n' is and use that in the denominator? right now your code will work out 1+2!*2+3!*3+...

You could actually use something similar to your factorial method

```
    static double GetDenominator(double n)
    {
        double res = 1;
        for (double i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            //insert code here 

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct as per your question , also your code won't execute as you have a function inside your GetSumSix function. I have put some helping points in below code so you will understand how the logic works.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var Calculate = GetSumSix(3);
    Console.WriteLine("The Answer is " + Calculate);
  }

  public static double GetSumSix(int n)
  {
    int i; 
    double result = 0.0;
    int factorial = 1;
    string calculatedFormula = String.Empty;
    string FinalFormat = String.Empty;
  
    //Find n!
    for(int x=n;x>=1;x--)
    {
      factorial *=  x; 
    }
    
    // Find Denominator (1+1/2+1/3+…+1/n)
    for (i = 1.0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        result += GetDenominator(i, ref calculatedFormula);
        FinalFormat += calculatedFormula;
    }

    result = factorial/result;
    Console.WriteLine("Calculated Formula is:"+ factorial +"/(" + FinalFormat +")When N is :" + n);
    return result;
  }

  public static double GetDenominator(double n, ref string cal)
  {
    if (n == 1)
    {
        cal += n + "+ ";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cal = "1/" + n + "+ ";
        return 1 / n;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Static local functions are perfectly valid in C#8. Your answer ignores the fact that his method needs to sum `f(x) = x!/(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/x)` for `x` in the range `[1..n]` not simply calculate the final denominator.

Comment: Thanks Corey regarding the c# 8 feature update. I totally forgot about the factorial bit, I have added to the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

`The Lemon`'s answer is correct, you're not accumulating the denominator of the sequence so what you were calculating was:

```
 f(n) = 1!/1 + 2!/(1/2) + 3!/(1/3) + ... n!/(1/n)
```

Since both the numerator and denominator of each term are algorithmically linked to the values in the prior term you can simply update them each pass through the loop. This is (slightly) faster and fairly easy to read.

```
public static double GetSumSix(int n)
{
    double factorial = 1;
    double denominator = 1;
    double accum = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        factorial *= i;
        denominator += 1.0d/i;
        accum += factorial / denominator;
    }
    
    return accum;
}
```